# STM32 virtual com port description in Windows Device Manager

Tags: stm32

i am implementing a Virtual Com Port using an STM32. I would like to have the device appear in Windows Device Manager with a customer desciption. at the moment it appears under "Ports (COM & LPT)" as "STMicroelectronics Virtual COM Port).

Would anyone know how to do this? I have tried updating the string descriptors in usb_desc.c but this does not seem to change how the device appears in Device Manager.

Comment: There are two different USB libraries provided by ST, which apply to different microcontrollers. We need to know which microcontroller you used to know which Library it is.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the string "STMicroelectronics Virtual COM Port" does not come from the device descriptor loaded onto the STM32. It comes from the STM32 VCP Windows driver's .inf file and may be edited with a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Those strings are indeed coded in the file usb_desc.c from the ST USB-Library.

Windows sometimes does not detect the change in your device descriptors, since the device USB descriptors are saved in the system the first time you connect the device.

When you plug the device again Windows checks its Vid/PID (Vendor ID - Product ID) and uses what it already knows about the device.

When Windows doesn't recognize the modification. You should try to assign another VID/PID to the device or delete the device instance from the device manager (right click->uninstall) and then plug the device again.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply uninstall the driver and try again because as Etienne said: Windows sometimes does not detect the change in your device descriptors.